# pinia: Define getters and actions in function notation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I am in the process of implementing a pinia store in function notation and am wondering how to declare the getters and actions.

Are these implemented as simple functions without distinction?

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import HttpService from '../services/BaseHttpService';
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

const httpService = new HttpService('/users');
    
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
    const authedUser = ref(new User())
    const users = ref<User[]>([])

    function authed() {
        return typeof authedUser.value['@id'] === "string";
    }

    function login(data: { email: string, password: string }) {
        const http = new HttpService('/login');
        return http.post(data).then((response) => {
            authedUser.value = response
            users.value = [...users.value, response]
        })
    }

    function getter() {
        return users.value;
    }

    function action(id: number) {
        httpService.get(id).then((response) => {
            users.value = [...users.value, response]
        })
    }

    return {authedUser, users, authed, login}
})
```

Comment: I believe this will botch typing. There are reasons to define a state in a function but I don't see a necessity for getters, etc. Currently you don't use Pinia features at all, you could just define a store with the internals of state function as is.

Comment: @EstusFlask This is just a "extended" basic example form the pinia website: https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#basic-example and i only want to know, how to define the getters

Comment: You can likely do this with `computed`s, which getters basically are.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you could use a `computed` variable to have getters and setters. I'll give a solution in TypeScript, which should work in Javascript if you remove the type annotations. I found my initial solution on [this issuecomment](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/447#issuecomment-1455285437) which a bit above [says](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/447#issuecomment-1454144548):

> The interface to write against is:
>
> ```js
> export declare interface WritableComputedOptions<T> {
>    get: ComputedGetter<T>;
>    set: ComputedSetter<T>;
> }
> ```

which would become something like (I didn't know the workings of your User class, so it's maybe a bit broken):

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import HttpService from '../services/BaseHttpService';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

const httpService = new HttpService('/users');
    
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
    const users = ref<User[]>([])
    const authedUser = computed<User | null>({
        get: () => {
             // find the (single) user that is logged in.
             let authedUsers = users.value.filter((user: User) => {user.isLoggedIn()})
             // return the user that is logged in and null otherwise
             return authedUsers.length === 1 ? authedUsers[0] : null
        },
        set: (user: User) => {
             //check if there is a logged in user(s)
             let authedUsers = users.value.filter((user) => {user.isLoggedIn()})
             if (authedUsers.length >== 0) {
                 authedUsers.forEach((authedUser: User) => {authedUser.logOut()}
             }
             if (users.value.includes(user) === false){
                 users.value.push(user)
             }
             user.logIn()
      }
        }
    })

    function login(data: { email: string, password: string }) {
        const http = new HttpService('/login');
        return http.post(data).then((response: User) => {
            authedUser.value = response
            // we already do this in the setter function
            // users.value = [...users.value, response]
        })
    }

    return {authedUser, users, login}
})
```

Not sure if mutating `users` when setting `authedUser` is an antipattern though...